# Mounting a board/sign to a tree without harming it

Tags: tree-care, light, design, weather

I'm looking for suggestions on mounting a board vertically to a tree but without drilling into the tree or harming it.

I was looking for some type of bracket or strap that would withstand multiple years of weather (i.e., not rust or disintegrate after one+ year of weather). I live in the PNW, so rain and moisture are an issue. The tree is an established and mature walnut.

The board will support lighted house numbers and will be about 30" long by 3-4" wide (final width tbd), so I'll secure it in at least two spots, maybe three. The trunk of the tree has a circumference between 60-70" depending on the spot along the trunk.

Comment: In a few years the tree may over-grow any fastener and cover it; pushing off anything attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions

1. Use a marine grade rope to tie it. It will last several years.
2. Use a glue or adhesive to stick it to the bark. Something like Ados F2

On the other hand  in my experience, most trees would survive a few holes drilled into them.

Comment: Yes, drill 3 holes and the tree will not care in the least.